# Changing list's elements using a given dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am confused how to change elements of list (y) using given dictionary(mydict).

```
x = [11,12,13,14,15,16]

y = [1,2,3,3,2,1]

mydict = {'1': 'red',
        '2': 'blue',
        '3': 'green'}
```

I tried as follows:

```
result = []

for i,j in zip(x,y):
    color = mydict[j]
    result.append(color)
```

The expected answer should be:

```
result =  ['red','blue','green','green','blue','red']
```

Comment: `'1'` is not the same as `1`

Comment: why are you zipping `x` and `y` and ignoring `i`?

Comment: Your current output is missing from your question. Or do you get an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your keys are strings, not integers. You'd have to convert one or the other.

Converting `j` is easiest:

```
for i, j in zip(x, y):
    color = mydict[str(j)]
    result.append(color)
```

but the better option is to fix the dictionary:

```
mydict = {1: 'red',
          2: 'blue',
          3: 'green'}
```

which could be replaced by a list:

```
colors = [None, 'red', 'blue', 'green']
```

Either way, you can produce the expected output with a list comprehension:

```
result = [colors[i] for i in y]
```

You never actually use the values from `x`.

Demo:

```
>>> colors = [None, 'red', 'blue', 'green']
>>> [colors[i] for i in y]
['red', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'red']
```